# Python expected indent error

Tags: python, indentation

[image: It says expected indent can't figure out how to fix it.]

Here is a picture of my problem in idle it says that I have an expected indent error and can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 8):

All your docstrings should be aligned one more step: they should line up with the code inside the methods, not with the method definitions.

Answer (score 3):

You have to indent the doc strings to the same level as your code.